# Osmbonuspack: show name of Marker on the map

Tags: android, osmdroid

Using the nice / new osmbonuspack package:

Is there a way to show the name (or title) of the Marker immediately on the Map?

So, without tapping the Marker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you, MKer, for extending the class.

Below, this is my implementation showing text on the Map. Hope this helps others.

```
public class MarkerWithLabel extends Marker {
Paint textPaint = null; 
String mLabel = null; 

public MarkerWithLabel(MapView mapView, String label) {
    super( mapView);
    mLabel = label; 
    textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor( Color.RED);
    textPaint.setTextSize(40f);
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
}
public void draw( final Canvas c, final MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
    draw( c, osmv); 
}
public void draw( final Canvas c, final MapView osmv) {
    super.draw( c, osmv, false); 
    Point p = this.mPositionPixels;  // already provisioned by Marker
    c.drawText( mLabel, p.x, p.y+20, textPaint); 
 }
}
```

In the code you could add:

```
marker = new MarkerWithLabel( mv, label);
marker.setTitle( label); 
etc
```

Comment: People that answer their own question deserver a medal, thank you <3!

Answer (score 0):

Of course! Very easy:

```
myMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: This will show the complete info window, in my case with buttons, etc. 

What I need is just to show the title of the marker. 

On my map I show e.g. 15 markers at once.

Comment: Then you have to sub-class Marker and implement your own drawSafe.

Comment: Well, easy to say that to do. Marker was a sub-class of SafeDrawOverlay, and there are strange issues related to SafeDrawOverlay, when drawing something which is not a Bitmap. I just changed that: Marker is now a subclass of Overlay, and drawing a text on the Canvas at a projected point works fine.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What a service you changed the Marker. 

Can you please give an example?